# Text and image on the same row

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I have a logo and a header image. When ever I try to centre the header image, it seems to go to the next row. How do I keep it on the same row?

[Website](http://readingcricketclub.com/new)

Thanks

Comment: use "float:right" applied to logo image and put its <img> tag prior to the header. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell Could you explain that a tad bit more (or send a jsFiddle!). Thanks

Comment: Please put your original code in jsFiddle, then I will take a look at it. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell Here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ86G/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ86G/1/

Your images are both inline elements. So just remove the div and align both images vertically:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The combination the removal of unessessary code and this should suffice.

Comment: this is the way to go!

Comment: He wants it centrally aligned, rather than vertically aligned, I think (presumably with the badge to the left).  Inline-block elements cannot be centrally aligned like this.

Answer (score 0):

The div is a block element, which causes it to appear on a new row.

```
    <div align="center">
<img width="500" height="auto" src="img/text.fw.png" alt="RCC">
</div>
```

Either remove the div and position the image with margin, or use position:absolute to make it appear in a layer on top of the logo above.

```
<div align="center" style="position:absolute;top:40px;width:100%;text-align:center">
<img width="500" height="auto" src="img/text.fw.png" alt="RCC">
</div>
```

(Inline styles used for demonstration only)

You could also give the div a negative margin-top to shunt it up the page.

Another would be to make the badge a background image of the div, and put the text on top.... many possible solutions.

Comment: How would I position the image with margin (can you tell (I'm a n00b))

Comment: It is built on Foundation, I need to keep its resposiveness!